# How to find the first non-zero element in each row of a matrix in r?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large matrix 10000x3000 and I would like to locate the first non-zero element in each row. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you consider a "nul" element? `NA`? `NaN`? `0`? `NULL`?

Comment: by null I mean 0. Thank you for asking

Comment: `apply(x!=0,1,function(x) which(x)[1])`

Comment: Thanks Ben and thanks MrFlick for the suggestions. In fact the problem is more complex, but I thought if I can have the answer to my question, I can easily do the other part. For those who want to help, here is my goal:

Comment: Thanks Ben and thanks MrFlick for the suggestions. In fact the problem is more complex, but I thought if I can have the answer to my question, I can easily do the other part. For those who want to help, here is my goal: I have a matrix M which starts, at each row, with zeros and then non-zeros values. I would like an incremental value k=1, 2, ..., K  at each row from the first non-zero value with K the last column of the row. For instance, if one row as 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 1 1, I will transform it to c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1)+ (0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)=c(0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7) here K=6

Comment: @josilber: I didn’t attempt anything because I did know where to start. The idea was to locate, in each row, the column where we have the first non-zero value. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will return the first non-zero element from each row.

```
#test data
set.seed(15)
mm<-matrix(ifelse(runif(9*12)<.3, 0, rpois(9*12,1)) , ncol=12); mm

#first non-zero value from each row.
apply(mm,1, function(x) head(x[x!=0],1))
```